# Ordering Aggregation Buckets by Score

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

Is it possible to order the aggregation bucket by score?

```
"aggs": {
    "UnitAggregationBucket": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "unitId",
        "size": 10,
        /* "order": order by max score documents per bucket */
      }
    }
  }
```

I have seen [this document](https://www.google.com/search?q=term%20aggregation%20order%20by%20score&rlz=1C1CHYZ_enNZ618NZ618&oq=term%20aggregation%20order%20by%20score&aqs=chrome..69i57.5982j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) which explains the default order is doc_count, but I cannot find out if it is possible and how to order the buckets by score.

Comment: You want to order the buckets by the score of what? scores are only available per document in the hits section, not in aggregations.

Comment: @Val, would it be possible to order by the max score of all documents in each bucket?

Comment: Ok, I see, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do that like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    ...
  },
  "aggs": {
    "UnitAggregationBucket": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "unitId",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "score": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "score": {
          "max": {
            "script": "_score"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot.... Do you know how I can write the second part using NEST? i.e.       "aggs": { "score": { "max": {  "script": "_score"  } }  }

Comment: I'm not a NEST expert, but I don't see why not. Check here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-aggregations.html